# How does one determine the minimum patch version of Python supporting a __future__ functionality?

Tags: python, version, cpython

I am a maintainer for a Python library that is considering supporting [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/), now in Python3.10

Our library currently supports Python3.8+ and so we figure that the `__future__` inbuilt library will allow us to make use of this. We do however want to be very explicit in the versions of Python we support.

[Python3.8.0](https://peps.python.org/pep-0569/) was released at roughly the same time as PEP 604 was introduced, and it likely launched with a `__future__` library that did not already have a working implementation of PEP 604, so this was probably added to Python`__future__` in a patch release that came later.

What I would like to know is the following:

1. Generally, are the features backported to `__future__` added in tow with stability/security updates to the specified minor version of Python, or are the features offered by `__future__` set at the date of initial release for a new minor Python version (ie: `Python X.Y.0`)?
2. Is PEP 604 available in Python3.8.0 via the `__future__` library? If not, when was it introduced to Python3.8's `__future__`?
3. Is there somewhere in the body of Python documentation that details the exact point releases where new features are backported to minor releases of Python via `__future__`?

Comment: `from __future__ import annotations` works from Python 3.7, at which point your annotations can contain whatever you like (including this union type syntax). PEP 604 doesn't have its own future import, in Python 3.8 or otherwise. The things are do are listed in https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/__future__.html along with when they were introduced and when they're no longer needed.

Comment: Does this mean that the new union type syntax has been available since Python3.7? How was this feature made available in Python3.7.0 long before any implementation of it was it available? I would like to know if it came later via an updated `__future___` or was it always offered via `__future__`?

Comment: Insofar as [postponing evaluation of annotations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/) means they can be whatever you like, yes. Then the specific syntax only matters when they actually get evaluated.

Comment: The new union type *syntax* was always available; types and type hints just didn't implement any *semantics* around it until Python 3.10. Futures are never added retroactively. They allow you to opt *in* to features "now", before they become mandatory in a future version. (Put another way, `__future__` is just a parser flag implemented via the module import system; it doesn't actually provide any new code.)

Comment: True, it was never _syntactically_ invalid, but postponing evaluation avoids the _runtime_ error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'type' and 'type'`.